# browser displays 'cannot load /xxx' when trying to modify input field using javascript, node.js and express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I just want to preface this that I am still learning so there is probably something that I am just missing, but this has me completely stumped.

I am building an html form where selecting one of the items in a select element causes an input element to update with some corresponding data fetched from a database.

the select element has an onchange event that fires this code:

```
function updateLocation(e){
  //perform xmlhttp request to node.js
  getRecord([asset = e.value], 'get', '/assetLocation', function (location) {
    console.log(location)
  })
}
```

the getRecord function looks like this (the try catch is just to try and figure out this issue i am having):

```
//request records from database
function getRecord(data, queryType, id, callback){
  try{
    const encodedData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
    const xhttp = newXMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open(queryType, `${id}?data=${encodedData}`);
    xhttp.onload = function(){
      if (this.status == 200){
        callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
      }else{errorParser(this)}
    }
    xhttp.send();
  } catch (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

here is my node.js route for this request (it's not actually querying the database just to eliminate that, but the database query does normally work):

```
app.get("/assetLocation", (req, res) => {
  const assetName = JSON.parse(req.query.data)[0];
  try{
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({'test':'test'}))
  } catch (err) {
    res.status = 500
    sendResponse(res, err)
  }
});
```

when I step through the program, everything appears to work as it should, but when i make it to the line where node.js sends the response back to the client, the .onload event never fires and instead the browser just jumps directly to 'cannot GET /undefined'. the console gets wiped in chrome when this happens so it's difficult to see what error pops up but in firefox you can retain it and and I can see that it throws a 404 error.

no error is thrown anywhere in the code that I can find.

Some stuff that I have seen happen intermittently which I can't explain:

once or twice before the 'cannot GET /undefined' came up, and only in firefox, the response did make it back to the browser, and I was able to see the 'test:test' object in the repsonseText property, but then the browser just went to the 'cannot GET /undefined' page anyway when I stepped to the next line.

sometimes the browser jumps to 'cannot GET /undefined' before i even step to the line where node.js sends the response, which really baffles me.

Answer (score 0):

okay I obviously missed the simplest thing here because i got it working.

instead of [asset = e.value] i should have used {'asset' : e.value}

not sure why I had square brackets in there!